# rake db:migrate always outputs SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Every time I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following output:

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

This started after installing `rspec-rails` gem.

When I try to run a test I get the following output:

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
.   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
.

Finished in 0.03 seconds (files took 1.5 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

I created the test_database and ran migrations. Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

Rspec-rails generated this:  it's a check to automatically run any pending migrations before any tests are run.  It's in  your `/spec/rails_helpers.rb` file and says:

```
# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

It's a really good idea to leave that line in there so that you don't inadvertently run tests when your database is not in good/complete/expected state (which can happen if you have migrations hanging around that you've forgotten to run).

Comment: Yes I saw that and I don't have migrations to run. It's all up to date.

Comment: You're just seeing the SELECT statement that is being used to see if you have any migrations that need to be run.  It's not finding any (the SELECT is returning 0 records).  If it *did* find any records (if the SELECT statement found > 0 records), then you *would* see an error message along the lines of '.... there are migrations to run.  Test aborted...'  
Just like Taryn East said: it's not an error.   You're just seeing the system do the required check.  Your tests are passing.

Comment: So you're say this is proper output for an rspec test? Because I don't think so..

Comment: You can read more about the migration check in the Github repo for rspec-rails.  Here's a note about it in the changelog: "Rails 4.x ActiveRecord::Migration pending migration checks" https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks     What about the SELECT statement is bothering you?  (I'm not trying to be argumentative; I'm trying to understand your point of view and why it looks suspicious to you.)

Comment: Only because it is now logging that SELECT statement is what is making it suspicious to me. I was able to modify the `rails_helper` to stop showing ActiveRecord queries when running test. Also the test taking 1.5s to run is suspiciously slow.

Comment: Go ahead and comment out that migration check for now. (But make sure you re-instate it at some point.)  You now understand where it comes from, that it's there to help ensure your system in a good state before the tests begin, and you know how to find out more about it.      If you're not using Spork + Guard, you can look in to getting those set up -- your tests will go a *lot* faster since the entire Rails environment won't have to be reloaded each time. (If you are already using them, then ya -- 1.5s is sloooow.)

Comment: @aenw  Your answer helped me with finding out why a Rails 4.2 Engine, using RSpec, would automatically drop tables IN MY TEST DATABASE! The database is created by another application and this gem should not create or drop them. I was going bonkers in trying to understand MySQL2 errors and then why my test database was being deleted!

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr it's not an error

`schema_migrations` is the table in which rails stores the VERSION-number of all migrations that it has run for the current environment's database.

It will always check this when migrating a database (which it does before specs too), to see if there are any pending migrations that have not yet been run for this database.

Comment: Ok maybe not an error but how do I fix my test output? It may not be an error but it isn't properly functioning either. Technically nothing should happen when I run `rake db:migrate` if migrations are up to date.

Comment: There is nothing to fix... this is exactly what *should* happen when you run rake db:migrate - rails checks the set of migrations to see which ones have been run. It's possible you recently changed logging-levels in your environment? if so - you now see things that have always been happening, just haven't been logged before

Comment: I have not changed any logging events: "It's possible you recently changed logging-levels in your environment" 

This is why I'm suspect something is not right...

Comment: Yeah working on it.. Just reflex comment... Not to leave you hanging.. Thanks!